# KeyError when extracting data from a pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

In the following ipython3 session, I read differently-formatted tables and make the sum of the values found in one of the columns:

```
In [278]: F = pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/feature_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", skip
     ...: rows=2, usecols=[6]).sum()

In [279]: S = pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", us
     ...: ecols=[6], header=None).sum()

In [280]: S
Out[280]: 
6    3551266
dtype: int64

In [281]: F
Out[281]: 
72    3164181
dtype: int64

In [282]: type(F)
Out[282]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [283]: type(S)
Out[283]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [284]: F[0]
Out[284]: 3164181

In [285]: S[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-285-5a4339994a41> in <module>()
----> 1 S[0]

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
--> 603             if not is_scalar(result):
    604                 if is_list_like(result) and not isinstance(result, Series):
    605 

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3323)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3026)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4009)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8146)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8090)()

KeyError: 0
```

**How come the `F` and `S` objects have different behaviours if they result from similar operation (`sum`) and are of the same type (`pandas.core.series.Series`)?**

What is the correct way to extract the value I want (the sum of a column)?

#### Edit: Trying solutions:

```
In [297]: F["72"]
Out[297]: 3164181

In [298]: S["6"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4009)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8125)()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-298-0127424036a0> in <module>()
----> 1 S["6"]

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    602 
--> 603             if not is_scalar(result):
    604                 if is_list_like(result) and not isinstance(result, Series):
    605 

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3323)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3026)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4075)()

KeyError: '6'
```

Further investigating:

```
In [306]: print(S.index)
Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')

In [307]: print(F.index)
Index(['72'], dtype='object')

In [308]: S[6]
Out[308]: 3551266
```

So the two objects ended up having different types of indices. This kind of behaviour reminds me of R...

It seems that `header=None` resulted in columns indexed by numbers for `S`, whereas the absence of `header=None` combined with `skiprows=2` resulted in the index being generated from data read on the third row. (And this revealed a bug in the way I parsed the data in pandas...)

Comment: I'm surprised `F[0]` works. I would have expected `F[72]` and `S[6]` to work. Or otherwise `F.iloc[0]`...

Comment: `F[0]` works when you have an unnamed column. In that case, your columns will be a `RangeIndex`. If you are trying to select the _first row subslice_, you need `F[0:1]`.

Comment: Alternatively, to clear up any confusion, you should use explicit `iloc` based indexing. `F.iloc[0]` will _always_ mean the first row and nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#select first value of one element series
f = F.iat[0]
#alternative 
#f = F.iloc[0]
```

Or:

```
#convert to numpy array and select first value
f = F.values[0]
```

Or:

```
f = F.item()
```

And I think you get error, because no index value `0`.

As IanS commented should be working select by index value `6` and `72`:

```
f = F[72] 
#f = f.loc[72]

s = S[6]
#s = S.loc[6]
```

Sample:

```
F = pd.Series([3164181], index=[72])

f = F[72] 
print (f)
3164181

print (F.index)
Int64Index([72], dtype='int64')

print (F.index.tolist())
[72]

f = F[0] 
print (f)
```

> KeyError: 0

You get one integer index in `S`, because parameter `header=None` - pandas add default index (`0,1,...`). For `F` is used `6th` column called `'72'` - it is string. There is difference.

Comment: Your solutions all work (except the last edit), thanks. But I'm puzzled why the two objects behave differently.

Comment: Selecting by index values works only for F, and using quotes.

Comment: You can check `print (S.index)` - it is value which need be in `[]`

Comment: `print(S.index)` -> `Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')`, `print(F.index)`
-> `Index(['72'], dtype='object')`: One has a number as index, the other has a string.

Comment: so need `f = F['72']`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to define the separator of each file. Otherwise, the read_table will read one line as a column.

Try something like:
pd.read_table(filename, sep=";", usecols=[6]).sum()

Comment: Both files use the same separator (tab). What changes is the number of columns, and that in the F case, there are a some header lines I need to skip.